# Would it be OK to install a water pressure regulator where the supply line enters my home?

Tags: water-pressure

Hi I have high water pressure 120 psi and no regulator vavle installed at my home.  My home is on a slab with a very small water meter box in the front yard.  The box is too small to accommodate the regulator underground on the downstream side of the meter.

Would it be OK to install the regulator inside my home where the supply line enters?  My line enters the garage and runs laterally through the walls throughout the house.  I want to cut an access panel in the drywall in the garage and install the regulator in the wall cavity between the 2x4 studs.  Any thoughts or ideas as greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you have found the one and only entrance of the supply line before it splits off?  That would be my main concern.

Comment: A regulator would limit the pressure. you also want to make a access door to be able to repair if needed and maintain the firewall between the Garage and living space.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are in a non-freezing climate. In freezing climates, it's very common to have a pressure regulator / pressure reducing valve inside the house, since it would freeze (or be in an inconveniently deep hole) outside the house.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an expansion tank on the cold supply at the water heater. Your meter probably has a backflow preventer in it (check valve) which will not help when pressure builds up in the house.